# Can't give write permissions to /root?

Tags: 14.04, permissions, root, chmod

I am trying, and failing, to give the user `jenkins` write access to `/root`.

Firstly: Yes, this is not something you would normally recommend doing. But for some reason Jenkins is insisting on writing and reading from the roots home directory. If you know immediately why it is doing that and how to stop, I will gladly look at it. But for now, as much as it goes against my better judgement, I need to give jenkins write permissions to `/root`.

On a safety note, there is nothing in `/root` that I have not put there myself.

This is what I am running (initially logged in as root):

```
~# chmod o=rwx /root
~# sudo su jenkins
/root$ touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Permission denied
/root$ cd .pip/
/root/.pip$ touch test
/root/.pip$ ls
pip.conf  pip.log  test
```

So this is the weird thing.

I have already given read/write permissions to the subfolders within `/root` which works fine. But I still cannot actually write to the directory itself.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Do you really mean `/root` ? The root directory is `/`

Comment: Is there a pre-existing (root owned) file called `test` in `/root`? Regardless, I think you should start a separate Q about your apparent jenkins configuration problem.

Comment: @CarlH I really mean `/root`. thankfully I don't have to give permissions to `/`

Comment: @steeldriver just did a sanity check and no, there is no file already called `test` in the directory.

Comment: Try `chmod -R o=rwx /root`

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Done that, I believe that is why the subdirectories are writable. but `/root` still isn't

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to giving everyone write access to the `/root` directory is to use acls to give the jenkins user access to the `/root` directory.

```
~# setfacl -m "u:jenkins:rwx" /root
```

Most Ubuntu installs already have Access Control Lists enabled, but you might have to first install the `acl` package. Additionally, you can and the `R` flag to make the action recursive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it out and no change. As well as with the recursive flag.